# How to Concatenate duplicate records from a table as a comma separated record in a view?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I need to create a new view using MySQL that concatenates all names if they have the same id;

Ex: Table: sample_table

```
profile_id  food
----------  ----
1           Apple
2           Banana
2           Orange
3           Lemon
3           Potato      
3           Grapes
```

Should be

vw_sample_view

```
 profile_id  food
 ----------  ----
 1           Apple
 2           Banana, Orange
 3           Lemon, Potato, Grapes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql's [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to achive the desired outcome:

```
select profile_id, group_concat(food)
from yourtable
group by profile_id
```

All you need to do is to include the above query into a [create view command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).

Comment: ... and we need to be cognizant of the affect that group_concat_max_len *in the session* that queries the view will have on the result from the view. To get the spaces in there after the commas, we'd need to override the default separator. by specifying SEPARATOR ', ' in the group_concat. and if we want the list to be ordered, we'd need to add an ORDER BY in the group_concat. If we don't want duplicates, specify DISTINCT.

Comment: And this is why I linked the mysql manual page containing the description of group_concat() for the benefit of the OP.

Comment: And how much would you be willing to bet that there will be a subsequent question... how do i write a query that splits a column containing a comma separated list into separate rows, each with one value from the list ?

Comment: I think the follow up question will more likely to be around how to join the comma separated values on the fruits table to get additional details about the fruits in the list.

Comment: I'd be willing to put a banana up as a wager.  And next up... why is my query from a view *so slow*.